# ¿Cómo volver al inicio de una página cuándo se recarga?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo la siguiente duda, ¿Cómo podría hacer para que mi pagina web regrese al inicio de esta cuando un usuario apriete el botón de volver a cargar pagina  el navegador?

Aún no he intentado con ninguna línea de código.

Answer (score 6):

Ejecutar [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) al terminar de cargar la página debiera lograrlo.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

```css
.alto {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.amarillo {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.azul {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="alto amarillo">
</div>
<div class="alto azul">
</div>
```

**Edición**: Dado que no siempre se puede recargar el *iframe* del snippet, he dejado una muestra en github: [volveralinicio.html](https://jachguate.github.io/SOExercises/597000/volveralinicio.html)

Comment: No ha funcionado solamente pone dos div con un color , no me regresa al recargar la pagina saludos

Comment: Los div son solo para que puedas hacer Scroll. Es algo que debieras probar fuera de la respuesta, pues dentro de ella no tienes forma de _recargar_ realmente dicha página.

Comment: Si se puede recargar solo el frame del snippet, y si funciona como se espera.

Comment: @Daniel, edité la respuesta, la probé fuera y realmente no estaba funcionando, pero ya con este cambio está. Puedes verla en funcionamiento en https://jachguate.github.io/SOExercises/597000/volveralinicio.html

Comment: Ahora si , funciona perfectamente , gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Para recargar el iframe: 1- Clic derecho en la vista previa. 2- Volver a cargar marco.

Comment: En todos los navegadores, en todos los sistemas operativos? Escribo este comentario desde Chrome en Android.